# Notice: Undefined index: image in D:\wamp\www\onlinesShop\newitem.php on line 21

Tags: php, mysql

I tr to upload image in my phpMYadmin with php and msqli But Got the mentioned error so practically everything will insert except the image.I Think every thing is good don't know where is the problem please help:(

here is the php:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $Name=$_POST['Name'];
        $Desc=$_POST['Desc'];
        $Image=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; //get error in this line

        echo $_FILES['image']['error'];//get error in this line


        $sql="INSERT INTO `items`(`Name`,`Description`, `image`) 
        VALUES('$Name','$Desc','$Image')";


        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){ 
        echo "new record";
        }
        else{echo"Wrong";}
        mysqli_close($con);
        }
        ?>
```

the html:

```
<form action="http://localhost/onlinesShop/newitem.php" method="POST" > 
            <table  id='table_admin'>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="116" height="50" align="left">Name</td>
                    <td width="466"><input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" title="Name" maxlength="200"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="290">Description</td>
                    <td><textarea name="Desc" cols="40" rows="15" id="textarea"></textarea></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    <td width="80"><input type="file" name="image" id="fileField" ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
        </form>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` within `<form>`. Check @Ghost answer it'll work

Comment: Nope I get the error again @NarendraSisodia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make sure you set the `<form>` with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` when you're dealing with file uploads:

```
<form action="newitem.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then after that, as usual, continue processing thru `$_FILES`:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $Name=$_POST['Name'];
    $Desc=$_POST['Desc'];
    $Image=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO items (Name, Description, image) VALUES(?, ?, ?)';
    $insert = $con->prepare($sql);
    $insert->bind_param('sss', $Name, $Desc, $Image);
    $insert->execute();

    if($insert->num_rows > 0) {
        echo 'insert okay!';
    }
}
```

Comment: it works @Ghost but all the info will show except the image coz in phpmyAdmin it shows as  D:wamp    mpphpE757.tmp instead of showing the directory can u help me with that?@Ghost

Comment: @LiLi you'll need to save the file first, using [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) then save the path wherein you saved it